# Typescript: typed access to class functions by index

Tags: typescript

I need to call the functions of the `ExampleOne` class based on the names of the fields of the `DataValues` class, taking values from there and passing them to the functions of an instance of the `ExampleOne` class

Tell me how to correctly write a function call through the indexer, as you can see there is some problem with the types

```js
class ExampleOne {
    f1(argStr: string): string {
        return `some text ${argStr}`;
    }
    f2(argNumber: number): string {
        return  `some text ${argNumber}`;
    }
}

class DataValues {
    f1: number = 64;
    f2: string = 'Hello';
}

function example() {
    const testClass = new ExampleOne();
    const data = new DataValues();

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        const functionName = key as keyof ExampleOne;
        const func = testClass[functionName];

        const arg: number | string = value;


        const result = func.apply(testClass, [arg]); 
/*                       | <---------- error this*
                         |
                         |
The 'this' context of type 
'((argStr: string) => string) | ((argNumber: number) => string)' 
is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 
'(this: ExampleOne, argStr: string) => string'.
Type '(argNumber: number) => string' is not assignable to type 
'(this: ExampleOne, argStr: string) => string'.
Types of parameters 'argNumber' and 'argStr' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2684) */

    console.log(result);
    }
}

example();
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDDGBsEMGdoAgKIA9IFsAO4CmB5AdlnAN7ACQAZgIwAUkATgOYDKALnQFxzRsCWeDASk7c6fBsTKk6WFgFc6eOAANoAe1SEWWJCzgASIvWZsAvkoDcZE2XIAmWowBys1ACMsHOHhfu6Qrrz8EqRSMvKKymoacFo6+oZOPh5mlqTW1mBQsHAAIpAskABqkOCyWPAkFJSc3m4ecAC8cABsACypdsKB4k0A5AASWODgqr2WGeSyeKAsPKqK2miYWNQCwaDz3DHlLADCWfBNBADuiCgY2PgrApZkG3hbACb5kI1eWKd5BcWl5au3FFUdDg1HuWwA2gBrLAATwANHAAG4lMoAXTgqnIcBwrgAVlgZgA6LB4Xh-Z4FARrSqkMG6SbTWbzRxoQhNaEwuAwOAczFnJaXAipWmbelTUBvLTcfYwaDghkzOZ4FkaVEAkUPXRGGpJYEAHwCoiCTWRv3VdLg0mgsnAuiaCsJkHQmBh1ClewOCPBRlRNxAcADcDBqmwhJGDGoVptLD9aWAGUWF2u5iAA)

Initially I tried to do this but it didn't work:

```js
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        const functionName = key as keyof ExampleOne;
        const func = testClass[functionName];

        const arg: number | string = value;

        const result = testClass[functionName](arg);
/*                                              | <--- error this
                                                |
                                                |
Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2345)
*/

    console.log(result);
    }
```

Comment: Haven't you mixed up f1 and f2? The f1 function in Example1 takes a string but in DataValues f1 is a number. Likewise the f2 function in Example1 takes a number but in DataValues f2 is a string. Aren't they supposed to match?

Comment: `arg: number | string` is not good enough.  We need to know which one it is and we need to know that it matches the `func` that we have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type FunctionCollection<V> = {
    [K in keyof V]: (_: V[K]) => string;
}

function applyFunctions<V>(fc: FunctionCollection<V>, dv: V): void {
    for (let key in dv) {
        console.log(fc[key](dv[key]));
    }
}

  /////////////
 // Example //
/////////////

class Values {
    f1: string = 'Hello';
    f2: number = 64;
}

class Functions {
    f1(argStr: string): string {
        return `some text ${argStr}`;
    }
    f2(argNumber: number): string {
        return  `some text ${argNumber}`;
    }
}

function example() {
    applyFunctions<Values>(new Functions(), new Values());
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mplDBm)

Comment: Is there anyway we can ensure that Values has the entire list of functions from Functions. Like is there a way that if you added "f3" you would get an exception or compile error saying you needed to add "f3" to values?

Comment: @chrispepper1989.  Is it okay if Values has more keys than Functions has?

Comment: I popped an answer below, i think it would have been fine for Values to have more, but ideally what I wanted was, whereever possible not to need to know the fact the functions existed already. I was essentially looking for reflection in TS

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who had a similar issue to me (I wanted to call all functions, not just the ones I knew the parameters of) and **If your willing to put some code in a .js file:**

This is how you can get *all* the function names in a class:

```js
    const classObject = new MyClass();
    const functionNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(classObject.__proto__);
```

You can call any function in a class by doing this

```js
    classObject[functionName](value);
```

Where possible I would say @md2perpe's answer is superior as its more concise , parameter aware and valid Typescript!.

However you can use this technique to call all functions, with parameters. Here is an example of how:

```js
function convertObjectToDictionary(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((result, key) => {
        result[key] = obj[key];
        return result;
    }, {});
}


function RunAllFunctionsInClassWithValues(
    classObject,
    parameterOverrides,
) {
    const functionNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(classObject.__proto__);
    const paramDict = convertObjectToDictionary(parameterOverrides);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < functionNames.length; i++) {
        let functionName = functionNames[i];

        if (functionName !== 'constructor') {
            
            try {               
                value = paramDict[functionName];
        
                classObject[functionName](value);
            } catch (e) {
                success = false;
                errorMessage = e.message;
            }

        }
    }
}

class MyClass
{
  Speak(text)
  {
    console.log(text);
  }
  QuackNTimes(number)
  {
    for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) 
        this.Speak(`Quack ${i}`);
  }
  Bark()
  {
     console.log("Woof");
  }
}

class MyParameters
{
    Speak = "Hello World";
    QuackNTimes = 4;
}

RunAllFunctionsInClassWithValues( new MyClass(), new MyParameters())
```

I do wonder if this could be improved to become valid typescript! However you can also take more advantage of the quirkyness of JS here: the optional parameters etc